# Setting product visibility via SQL (WordPress + WooCommerce)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

The following problem can be considered as a special case of adding categories to posts by SQL query [1], but answers relating to that general case are highly welcome too:

Let’s say we have 10.000 products and want to set their product visibility to “Hidden” (as if done 10.000 times, once for each product, in WP-admin). How can this be done safely with (which) SQL query?

I have some suggestions that *seem* to work (in practice, so far), based on an answer in [1] and some DB observations [2], but is there anything else (side-effects) that needs to be compensated for (vs. doing it all in WP-admin)? Diffing the DB dump before and after setting one product to “Hidden” via WP-admin shows that there are a few other things that differ than only “product_visibility”-related content, such as transient/cached options in wp_options (not a problem that these are out-of-sync), but there are other things like cron-related records too. And in general, there can be a lot and depending on plugins being used etc. Therefore, are there any default/common things that needs to be compensated for – or is it safe to do the following SQL queries without any extra care (and why)?

The SQL performed [2], after resetting all products to “Full” visibility – that I question with regards to possible compensation needed versus doing it all in WP-admin:

A) Setting “exclude-from-search” with:

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id) 
SELECT ID, '472512' FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='product'
```

and

```
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy 
SET count = '10000' 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '472512'
```

and then B) Setting “exclude-from-catalog” with:

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id) 
SELECT ID, '472513' FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='product'
```

and

```
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy 
SET count = '10000' 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '472513'
```

Thank you very much for any feedback/thoughts!

Sources:

[1] : [How to add category to all post by using sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262878/how-to-add-category-to-all-post-by-using-sql-query)

[2] : The term info ('472512' ~ "exclude-from-search", '472513' ~ "exclude-from-catalog) resulted from the query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_terms 
WHERE term_id IN (
    SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy 
    WHERE taxonomy = "product_visibility"
)
```

[I also posted this on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-product-visibility-via-sql/]

Comment: It'd be easier to just use the built-in Product Exporter and change the visibility there, re-import using their built-in importer.